# Java String best practice regarding pool

Tags: java, string

I have always wondered what the most effective way is of creating String's in Java. By this I mean strings that won't change in value.

Example:

```
String prefix = "Hi, I am ";
```

The `prefix` won't change but the postfix might.

- I don't want to make the `prefix` a `static final` variable as it will always stay alive in the JVM even if the class is rarely used...bla bla.
- and when I do the following:

  `String fullWord = ("Hi, I am "+_postFix);`

  I am guessing that the `"Hi, I am"` String value will remain in the Java String pool and I don't have the "overhead" of declaring the prefix as a variable.

Meaning my question boils down to this:

1. Will the Java String pool always be used when and when I don't declare a String variable using the `new` keyword?
2. Is it better to declare a String as a variable before using it?
3. How does the String pool work? Does the JVM detect that a same String value is often used and keeps referring to that String in JVM memory?

Comment: About your first sentence: Strings never change their value, they're immutable. The reference to them may change, that's all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. All literal `String`s are interned.
2. Write code that is easy to understand. It really is not worth trying to nano-optimise this.
3. All literal `String`s loaded by class loaders are interned, as are `String`s returned by `String.intern` (which is a slow way of doing it, in typical implementations).

Comment: I agree with #2, but there's value in knowing why stuff works, not just how to do it.